# Payload not found in Cache

Tags: wix, exe, burn, payload

I have an ExePackage which has two Payloads.

The first one is an msi file in the same folder as the Exe and it works.

The second one is also an msi file(Adobe Acrobat Reader) but in a sub folder where the Exe resides and does not work.

How should configure the Payload?

The ExePackage looks like this:

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.SetupPrereqs.TargetDir)setup.exe">
        <Payload SourceFile="$(var.SetupPrereqs.TargetDir)setup.msi"></Payload>
        <Payload SourceFile="$(var.SetupPrereqs.TargetDir)Adobe Reader XI\adberdr11000_en_us.msi"></Payload>
      </ExePackage>
```

The error message is as below:

```
EULA for components 'Adobe Reader XI' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\Ranjith\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD88AF.tmp\"
File 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5F65AFE70DE3058F30460C7DF1306453B0D509EA\Adobe Reader XI\adberdr11000_en_us.msi' not found.  Skipping file copy.
Error: The following package files could not be found:
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5F65AFE70DE3058F30460C7DF1306453B0D509EA\Adobe Reader XI\adberdr11000_en_us.msi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a payload to be laid out in a subfolder, specify that in `Payload/@Name`.

```
<Payload 
  Name="Adobe Reader XI\adberdr11000_en_us.msi"
  SourceFile="$(var.SetupPrereqs.TargetDir)Adobe Reader XI\adberdr11000_en_us.msi" />
```